# compare two tablles with respect to one column which is present in both tables in laravel6

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do a simple hotel booking system. I have 3 tables - **users** for user details
**rooms** for room details with foreign key userid and **room_numbers** for a number of rooms.
Actually my idea is when a user login he goes to the home page there one select column for room numbers,
here the values come from room_numbers table(only columns id and room number), a second field for check-in and third for checkout. I can insert all these data in a table called rooms with userid, perfect. But my question is if a user selects room number 101 from dropdown it is taken by that user so if another user cannot access room number 101.how can I obtain that? what changes should I make in tables?

this is my RoomController code

```
public function store()

{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'rooms' => 'required',
        'from' => 'required',
        'to' => 'required',
    ]);

    auth()->user()->rooms()->create([
        'rooms' => $data['rooms'],
        'from' => $data['from'],
        'to' => $data['to'],
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

I fetch room numbers in my bookroom.blade.php

```
<select id="rooms" class="form-control @error('rooms') is-invalid @enderror" 
name="rooms" value="{{ old('rooms') }}">
<option></option>
      @foreach($roomnumber_array as $data)
             <option value="{{$data->rooms}}">{{$data->rooms}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

the following is the table of my room

```
id userid rooms from      to
1  1      101   12-11-19  14-11-19
2  2      102   13-11-19  15-11-19
```

the following is my room numbers table

```
id rooms
1  101
2  102
3  103
4  104
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I think you are design the wrong table structures and their relationships.

Comment: For one, you do not need a separate table to maintain room numbers. Each room is associated with one number, so you can have it on the room table itself. You can have a separate table for bookings. In that table, you can associate users with rooms and booking dates. And you can always perform a check on the bookings table to see if there is a listing where the new `from` and `to` date falls within the existing `from`s and `to`s, if that makes sense.

Comment: can you suggest a way to solve this

Comment: i dont get you user3532758 please explain more clearly

Comment: I am trying to do , in the same page I have fields for select room, from date  and to date. I statically insert room numbers in that table and it will present when a user books room.

Comment: Have a look at this. Got loads of good information for your exact use case. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57512/db-design-of-a-room-booking-system